# Error from Cloudinary node package - Unexpected Token

Tags: node.js, express, npm, babeljs, cloudinary

As the title states, I am using the NPM package from cloudinary, I originally thought it was a configuration issue, but this is the 3rd time now I've run into this specific error and I can't seem to return anything about it from Google.

```
{ fieldname: 'name-of-input-key',
  originalname: 'leaf.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png' }
file uploaded to server
{ fieldname: 'name-of-input-key',
  originalname: 'leaf.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: 'leaf.png',
  path: 'uploads/leaf.png',
  size: 10227 }
/home/nolan/Node/cloudinary-skel/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js:989
  return {...hash1, ...hash2};
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nolan/Node/cloudinary-skel/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/cloudinary.js:4:17)
```

I'm assuming it's not running Babel or something because those parameters are new to ES6, but I can't seem to figure it out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code is blowing up on the modern ES6 spread operator.  You need to use babel along with babel-loader to compile these modules.

You will need to share your configuration for both your package.json and webpack.conifg.js.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar issue earlier this week. Finally found a solution to the problem, you could try this out and see if it works for you.

So, I specified **engines** in my **package.json** file, and it was set to version 8, but after changing it to version 10, everything worked fine.

Cheers